# Concatenated string and python dataframe generated string not matching

Tags: python-3.x, string, dataframe

I am trying to build a string from a dataframe which I will then submit to Google Trends using pytrends.

The construction of the string seems to work fine but when I pass it into pytrends it is rejected with a "ResponseError: The request failed: Google returned a response with code 400." error.

If I manually construct the equivalent string it works fine.

So, the problem is with the dataframe generated string...Except that when I print the manually constructed and the dataframe generated strings they appear identical...but when I do a comparison using == it says they are not the same.

This is the output of printing both strings and the comparison:

['hotels Tokyo', 'hotels Yerevan', 'hotels Niamey', 'hotels Tegucigalpa', 'hotels Ashgabat']

['hotels Tokyo', 'hotels Yerevan', 'hotels Niamey', 'hotels Tegucigalpa', 'hotels Ashgabat']

False

Here's the code which is set up to just query GTrends with the final row of data as above:

```
import pandas as pd
from pytrends.request import TrendReq
language = 'en-US'
pytrend = TrendReq(hl=language,tz=360,retries=10, backoff_factor=0.5)

gtrends_list_df = pd.read_csv('/app/jupyter_checkpoints/phil2/gt_full_splitty_sq_list2.csv')

for row in gtrends_list_df.itertuples(index=False):
    gtrends_kw_list = "['" + row[0] + "', '" + row[1] + "', '" + row[2] + "', '" + row[3] + "', '" + row[4] +"']" 
    ;


kw_list = ['hotels Tokyo', 'hotels Yerevan', 'hotels Niamey', 'hotels Tegucigalpa', 'hotels Ashgabat']
cat = 0
geo = ''
timeframe = '2019-02-01 2020-04-29'

print(kw_list)
print(gtrends_kw_list)
print(kw_list == gtrends_kw_list)

pytrend.build_payload(gtrends_kw_list, cat=cat, timeframe=timeframe, geo=geo, gprop='' )

int_over_time_df = pytrend.interest_over_time()
int_over_time_df
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was a type error. I was passing a string to the function when it wanted a list. When printed out they looked identical but were different data types.